# Django No redirections

Tags: django, view, httpresponse

I have a flash file which calls a url like: http://test.com/savethis/123456/

I just want my view to save "123456" in the database and return nothing.

After saving the values what do I do? If I redirect it it changes the page and that's bad. I could render a page, but I don't want to. I just want it to end and not throw any errors.

Comment: Is it only me who don't understand the question?

Comment: @S.Mark - no, I made a guess at what he wants. We'll see if I'm right!

Comment: My humble apologies for the abstract question and well @Dominic you were right :)

Comment: Besides there is a reason why my reput is 131 and you 13k :P

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557618/post-without-response-in-django-javascript-interaction

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your URLConf points to your desired view function, and write something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from my_models import MyModel

def myview(request, number):
    my_model = MyModel(my_field = number)
    my_model.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

The empty HttpResponse at the end there sends back a status code of 200 OK so that the browser or other server that connects to your endpoint knows the request was completed.

Comment: That should solve it :D basically I'm in flash so I think I would just ignore the response and it will work fine :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doing that thing from flash with navigateUrl is not really working. It gives me a pop up instead of doing it silently in the background.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're in a view function, which means someone's issued an HTTP request for something, which you have to respond to, so you can't just do nothing.

Either return an error code, or return an `HttpResponse`. You could just return an empty OK response (i.e. return HTTP response 200):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponse()
```