# POST without response in Django/Javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, django, view, httpresponse

I have a happy javascript based client that talks to my Django server-side code. I use several XMLHttpRequests for interactions and everything is fine there.  Now there is one user interaction where I'd like to receive user-sent info at the server, but I don't need/want a response.

As I understand Django all views MUST respond with an HttpResponse item. I can send back a blank one, or a HttpResponseNotModified response.   But anything I receive back seems to prompt the browser side to change to a blank screen.

I don't want to change pages, reload or anything. Just leave the browser session alone.  I don't need a confirmation, and don't mind if some of the POST sends are even lost among a large population of responses.

I COULD do an XMLHttpResponse and catch the response and ignore it. But I'm wondering if there is any way around that.

Comment: Without any code it will be hard to answer this one. Can you add the offending client-side code (assuming the server will just send an empty response)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a `Http204/No Content`, which tells the browser that your server acknowledged and processed your request but it didn't return anything and handle that appropriately in your application (however you want to).

If you're using jQuery (for example), then this will automatically go to your `success` handler, and if you have no control over that, you've done the best you could.

Read the full list of status codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)

Comment: Ah - thanks for that. Hadn't thought of 204 for some reason, was fixated on HttpResponse subclasses. I don't see a subclass for 204 in the Django Response code list, but a simple: return HttpResponse(status=204)   works just fine. :)

Comment: ...and supplemental to that, I found a different Django documentation page with more response objects. For those interested, see [this 'extras' page](http://django-extras.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/http-response.html)

Comment: @RossGK That is however the 3rd party app called `django-extras` and not included in standard Django

Comment: Yes - good point. Funny that some basic W3C response codes aren't incl in django.http

Comment: Well, that's why we have `HttpResponse(status=xxx)`.